# slideUp() and slideDown() does not work in jquery

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have used slideDown and slideUp in the code. The slideDown is working fine but the slideUp is not working. Can somebody correct me. I am new to javascipt. I am not sure if I am doing the right thing.

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="holder">
    <a class="btn-site">
        <span>More Stuff</span>
    </a>
</div>              
<div class="menus">
    <ul class="menu-content">
        <li><a href="">Stuff1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
$('.btn-site').on('click',function() {  
    if($(this).closest('div').is(':visible')){  
        $('.menus').slideDown('slow');
        $('span').addClass('arrw_down');        
    }else{
        $('.menus').slideUp('fast');
        $('span').removeClass('arrw_down'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tride `slideToggle();`?

Comment: i did. like change slideDown() and slideUp() to slideToggle()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** If you want your `SlideDown and slideUp` to work try first one.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn-site').on('click',function() {  
if($(this).parent().next("div").is(':visible')){  
 $(this).parent().next("div").slideUp('slow');
    $('span').addClass('arrw_down');        
}else{
 $(this).parent().next("div").slideDown('fast');
    $('span').removeClass('arrw_down');   
}
});
});

</script>

<div class="footer">
<div class="holder">
    <a class="btn-site">
        <span>More Stuff</span>
    </a>
</div>              
<div class="menus">
    <ul class="menu-content">
        <li><a href="">Stuff1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

try this:`$(this).closest('div')` will return the `.holder` div but you need to get `$(this).parent().next("div").is(':visible')` for `.menu` div.try with show and hide.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn-site').on('click',function() {  
 //console.log($(this).parent().next("div").is(':visible'));
if($(this).parent().next("div").is(':visible')){  
    $('.menus').hide('slow');
    $('span').addClass('arrw_down');        
}else{
    $('.menus').show('fast');
    $('span').removeClass('arrw_down');   
}
});
});

</script>

<div class="footer">
<div class="holder">
    <a class="btn-site">
        <span>More Stuff</span>
    </a>
</div>              
<div class="menus">
    <ul class="menu-content">
        <li><a href="">Stuff1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

another option can be using `slideToggle` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-site').on('click',function() {  
        $( ".menus" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
            if($('span').hasClass('arrw_down')){  
                $('span').removeClass('arrw_down');        
            }else{
                $('span').addClass('arrw_down');   
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: this works! thanks! BTW what is the use of `console.log though?`

Comment: it is just to check the value of `$(this).parent().next("div").is(':visible')` .nothing related to your implementation.

Comment: thank you so much! I just wonder why slideUp and slideDown won't work though.

Comment: @Sharon if you want to make slideUp and slideDown to work try the first one in all my answers from the updates.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn-site').on('click',function() {  
    $( ".menus" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        if($('span').hasClass('arrw_down')){  
            $('span').removeClass('arrw_down');        
        }else{
            $('span').addClass('arrw_down');   
        }
    });
});
```

.addRemove() should be changed to .removeClass();

Comment: oh yeah that was a  mistake.But either slideUp won't work

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
$('.btn-site').on('click',function() {  
    if($(this).closest('div').is(':visible')){  
        $('.menus').slideToggle('slow');
        $('span').toggleClass('arrw_down');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
<div class="holder">
    <a class="btn-site">
        <span>More Stuff</span>
    </a>
</div>              
<div class="menus">
    <ul class="menu-content">
        <li><a href="">Stuff1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stuff4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```